# Setting text size according to label size

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

Why is my text not sized according to label. I have followed some others code.

```
Label title0 = new Label();
title0.setMinSize(50,250);
Text t1 = new Text("TITLE1");

Bounds bounds1 = title0.getBoundsInLocal();
Bounds bounds2 = t1.getBoundsInLocal();
double scaley1 = bounds1.getHeight()/bounds2.getHeight();

t1.setScaleY(scaley1);
title0.setText(t1.getText());
```

Comment: Not clear the final expected result. If possible could you draw somehow on paper at least and attach a screenshot.

Comment: Solved. I just needed to bind the text to the label. I had no prior idea of binding.